# android : apply clipChildren only for one child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_grand_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/ListView_grand_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>
////////////////////////////

ListView holds the below row layout. 

/////// row_layout.xml ///////
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView_child"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/heart_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>
////////////////////////////

I need to animate the child "ImageView_child" and move it outside the parent,
than I used below method :

disableClipOnParents(ImageView_child);
public void disableClipOnParents(View v) {
    if (v.getParent() == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) v).setClipChildren(false);
    }

    if (v.getParent() instanceof View) {
        disableClipOnParents((View) v.getParent());
    }
}
```

It worked fine, while animating **ImageView_child** it is no more clipped by it's parent. But while scrolling the list, **ListView_grand_parent** also comes over the **RelativeLayout_grand_parent** and action bar.

My requirment is :

- **ImageView_child** should not be clipped by **ListView_grand_parent** and **RelativeLayout_grand_parent**.
- **ListView_grand_parent** should be clipped by **RelativeLayout_grand_parent**.

**Is it possible to disable the clipping only for one child ?**

Comment: Interesting, is it by intention or by mistake you keep row layout inside parent view

Comment: By intention I keep the row layout inside the parent, as it contains other childs too.

Comment: When you’re creating complex layouts use "include tag "

Comment: @KingofMasses how can I use it? Can you explain it more.